Issue with Missing Trace Metrics in Datadog After Production Build in Docker on AWS
I'm facing an issue with using Datadog for monitoring my application. In my local development environment (without using AWS), I have a Dockerfile that installs the Datadog agent and the dd-trace library. In this environment, everything works perfectly: I receive all metrics, including trace metrics (NestJS, database requests, requests from the frontend).
However, after the production build and deployment on AWS EC2 instances, the server continues to send only system metrics (CPU, memory), and the trace metrics (such as API requests and database calls) are not displayed.
prod -
.
local -

Dockerfile (snippet):
# Setting up environment variables
ENV DD_API_KEY=$DD_API_KEY DD_TRACE_REMOVE_INTEGRATION_SERVICE_NAMES_ENABLED=true
ENV DD_SITE="datadoghq.com" DD_APM_INSTRUMENTATION_ENABLED=host

# Install DataDog trace
RUN yarn add dd-trace --save
RUN export DD_INSTALL_ONLY=true && \
  (bash -c "$(curl -L https://s3.amazonaws.com/dd-agent/scripts/install_script_agent7.sh)"

Question:
Why do trace metrics work in my local development environment but not in production when deployed on AWS EC2? What additional steps might be needed to ensure that trace metrics are displayed correctly in production?
I would appreciate any help or suggestions!
I have tried adding the environment variable DD_TRACE_REMOVE_INTEGRATION_SERVICE_NAMES_ENABLED=true, but it didn't resolve the issue

The solution to my problem was to add the "datadog-agent restart" command after installing the agent.
In the datadog logs it was noticed that APM could not connect to port 5012, but after restarting everything worked.
